# Only using specific methodes of FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm building a website with symfony and for the user management I choose FOSUserBundle. Now.. I've build my form where I need an username, email and password (nothing more for now), which are the fields in my User table. But with FOSUserBundle it expects a lot more fields in my table like username_canonical, token, login_confirmation....

Is there a way to still use FOSUserBundle, but only with the 3 fields that I want to use? I was searching to maybe override it, but I couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use `FOS\UserBundle` your user class needs to implement `FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface`. It will provide the mandatory information. If you really want to have a simpler user interface (although `FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface` is pretty simple) you will need to create your own logic (e.g. fork `FOS\UserBundle`).